# JQuery select all dropdowns with exact matching class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, select, drop-down-menu

Here is my code

```
   $('select[class^="' +pnum+ '"]').each(function(){

          // Get price and prefix of each attributes
          var PricePrefix = AttributesAll[$(this).attr('class')]
          var PricePrefixSplit = PricePrefix.split("-with-");


          var AttPrice = parseFloat(PricePrefixSplit[0]);
          var AttPrefix = PricePrefixSplit[1];

          attributes_price = parseFloat(attributes_price);

          // Formulas for calculating attribute prices
          if (AttPrefix == '+') {
            attributes_price = attributes_price+AttPrice;
          } else if (AttPrefix == '%'){
            attributes_price = attributes_price * (1+(0.01*AttPrice));
          } else {
            attributes_price =  attributes_price-AttPrice;
          }



        });
```

I am trying to get all the select boxes with EXACT matching class name.

```
$('select[class^="' +pnum+ '"]').each(function(){
```

1) The above line of code get all select boxes that start with the matching class

2) `pnum` is an integer value I have tried to convert it into string but still the same issue

3) suppose there are classes class='1' and class ='10' it fetches both of them which it shouldn't

4) I have tried to replace the above line of code with

```
$('select[class="' +pnum+ '"]').each(function(){
```

doing so still doesn't work

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: `$('select[class="' + pnum + '"]')` should work can you see error in console?

Comment: @guradio I am seesing this warning in console


Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. in jquery 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Specifying integer to a class doesn't sound like a good idea. Unless you are having a css for that particular integer. If you are using it to purely identify the object, you can use a custom selector like

```
<select data-selector="1">
<option value="as">1st option</option>
</select>
```

and for retrieval you can follow what Muhammad suggested or you can use the following

```
alert($('select[data-selector="1"]').val())
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is not a good idea to specify classes as numbers, try to add some pseudo-word:

```
$('select[class^="el' +pnum+ '"]').each(function(){
```

Anyway I think the problems is your pnum variable, if it's lets say 1 - it will select all the classes starting with 1 beacouse you said so in the definition:

`$('select[class^=`

which treats all the classes starting with the defined word (the ^ char)

Going further you can define the variable storing classes names before the loop:

```
var elem = "el" + pnum;
$('select[class="'+elem+'"').each(function(){
```